# Access variables in existing model in linopy optimization problem

Tags: python, optimization

### Background

I am currently trying to set up a model in linopy for a real-time controller of an energy management system. Since the optimization problem differs from rtc to rtc (it is run for several households with different components), I need to create the variables and constraints dynamically. To do so, I first want to create the variables and subsequently create the constraints, primarily the balancing constraint.

Setting up the variables works but how do I access them to define constraints once they are added to the model? I was trying to use model.variables but this only returns strings and not the variable instance itself (see minimal example).

### Question

How do I access the variables in a linopy model from the model (e.g. model.get_variable(name='demand'))?

### Minimal example

```
from linopy import Model

# Optimization components (simplified as household demand and pv generation)
demand = 300  # unit: W (household demand that needs to be covered
pv = 200      # unit: W (maximum amount that pv can provide)
grid = 1000   # unit: W (maximum amount that grid can provide)

# Initiate model
model = Model()

# Create variables
model.add_variables(name='demand', lower=demand, upper=demand, integer=True)
model.add_variables(name='pv', lower=0, upper=pv, integer=True)
model.add_variables(name='grid', lower=0, upper=grid, integer=True)

# Create balancing constraint dynamically
balance = 0
for variable in model.variables:
    if variable == 'demand':
        balance -= variable
    elif variable in ['pv', 'grid']:
        balance += variable
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Variable "{variable}" not supported')

model.add_constraints(balance == 0, name='balance')

print(model)
```

When I tried the above method of calling the variables I get the expected error that a string cannot be added to an integer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 20, in <module>
    balance -= variable
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'int' and 'str'
```

### Solution

Thanks to @Kapocsi, here is the solution:

```
from linopy import Model

# Optimization components (simplified as household demand and pv generation)
demand = 300  # unit: W (household demand that needs to be covered
pv = 200      # unit: W (maximum amount that pv can provide)
grid = 1000   # unit: W (maximum amount that grid can provide)

# Initiate model
model = Model()

# Create variables
model.add_variables(name='demand', lower=demand, upper=demand, integer=True)
model.add_variables(name='pv', lower=0, upper=pv, integer=True)
model.add_variables(name='grid', lower=0, upper=grid, integer=True)

# Create balancing constraint dynamically
balance = model.add_variables(name='balance', lower=0, upper=0, integer=True)
for variable_name, variable in model.variables.items():
    if variable_name == 'demand':
        balance -= variable
    elif variable_name in ['pv', 'grid']:
        balance += variable
    else:
        pass

model.add_constraints(balance == 0, name='balance')

print(model.constraints['balance'])
```

which yields:

```
Constraint `balance`
--------------------
+1 balance - 1 demand + 1 pv + 1 grid = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the variables from the .variables container using either the "getitem" syntax or by accessing them as attributes:

```py
model.variables['demand']

model.variables.demand
```

You can also retain a reference when you initially add the variable to the model:

```py
demand = model.add_variables(name='demand', lower=demand, upper=demand, integer=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was just trying it out and it works in terms of accessing it. Another solution that I found for the for-loop was simply using `model.variables.items()`.

Unfortunately, I am unable to dynamically create the constraint as the types do not match (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'int' and 'Variable').

Comment: Try making `balance` a variable before adding another variable to it.

Comment: Thanks again! That did the trick. I will post the solution below the question.